# How to produce the following output?

Tags: c

Since i'm new in the programming world ,i'm facing little problem while writting program for this pattern .I tried many times but the result is not what i wanted ? 
 The pattern is :

```
 1 
 23 
 456 
 78910
```

What i have written is :-

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
void main() 
{ 
    int num = 1 , j = 1 , x = 1 , i = 1 ; 
    while( j <= 4 ) { 
        while( i <= num ) { 
            printf( "%d", x ) ; 
            x++ ; 
            i++ ; 
        } 
        num++ ; 
        i = ( i + 1 ) - num ; 
        j++ ; 
    } 
    getch() ; 
}
```

Comment: You do know that a loop like `int i = x; while (i < y) { ...; i++; }` is equivalent to `for (int i = x; i < y; i++) { ... }`?

Comment: It should be `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: If you want to print things on different lines, you need to do `printf("\n");` between the lines.

Comment: Newline is not output.

Comment: @Havenard It increments by 2 because 10 is 2 digits, everything else is just 1 digit. Count the numbers, not the digits.

Comment: @Havenard Put them all on the same line, and you will see the pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to print a newline after the inner loop:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
int main() 
{ 
    int num = 1 , j = 1 , x = 1 , i = 1 ; 
    while( j <= 4 ) { 
        while( i <= num ) { 
            printf( "%d", x ) ; 
            x++ ; 
            i++ ; 
        } 
        printf("\n");
        num++ ; 
        i = ( i + 1 ) - num ; 
        j++ ; 
    } 
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, it does produce the desired output. http://ideone.com/a1bceq only the `return` is missing.

Comment: I guess my downvote is as mysterious as all the upvotes for the other answer.

Comment: You get an upvote from me - just to balance the books

Comment: up vote for addressing OPs _apparent_ question.  (up vote on Ed's because it made me laugh)

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("1\n23\n456\n78910\n");
    return 0;
}
```

produces the output you desire

Comment: At best, this should be a comment.  :P

Comment: This shouldn't be anything.

Comment: Some serious optimization going on here.

Answer (score 0):

There is another example:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, num = 1, line = 4;
    for(i = 1; i <=  line ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", num);
            num++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With single loop:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# define LIMIT 100

int main(){
int i, prev=0, next=0, diff=1;
for(i=1;i<LIMIT;i++){
    printf("%d", i);next++;
    if(diff == next-prev){
        printf("\n");
        diff++;prev = next = 0;
    }
}
}
```